# Are Windows Phone 8.0 DLLs compatible with Windows Phone 8.1 apps?

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, windows-phone-8, dll

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 project, and a Windows Phone 8.0 library.
I need to add it into my Windows Phone 8.1 project; but at runtime, I have the following error:

> FileNotFoundException: could not load or assembly Microsoft.Phone,
>   Version=8.0.0.0. The system cannot find the file specified.

So my question is simple: are 8.0 libs compatible with Windows Phone 8.1 app ?
If not, what should I do ? Migrate them ?

Comment: Is it 8.1 silverlight or winrt?

Answer (score 0):

If your project is Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight, that it should work fine. If your project is Windows Phone 8.1 XAML (which seems more probable according to the error message) , then no, no way to use it without rewriting.

Comment: In fact, I need to use namespace Microsoft.Phone.Info. It seems to be available when creating a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight project, but not a WP 8.1 project (without SL). 
Also, can you tell me what's the drawbacks of a Windows Phone 8.1 SL app ? (will I be able to push it on the the store, is it compatible with Windows Phone 8.0 devices.... ?).